# 'Unknown database error' in MySQL after reinstalling

Tags: php, mysql

So after having some issues with MySQL's connection I decided to re-install it. I re-installed the entirety of MySQL 8.0 with the only difference being that I changed the authentication method (reason why I had to reinstall) and also in the process I gave my root a password.

Now when I log into PhpMyAdmin it for some odd reason allows me to log in with my old credentials (root + no password) and says the new password I chose is incorrect. And on top of that, I tried running a PHP script to connect to a pre-existing database in phpmyadmin and it gave me the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'forum-tutorial' in C:\wamp64\www\forum-tutorial\dbconn.php on line 6

So do I just have two phpmyadmin accounts now? How do I change to the new one? And how do I keep my database that I was using? I'm running WAMP server and they both appear to be using the port 3308 if that helps.

Edit: This is the PHP for the login script I made:

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'secret';
    $dbname = 'forum-tutorial';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname)
?>
```

Comment: `-`s are not good characters to use for identifiers. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html e.g. `Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers: ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)`

Comment: That's good to know but doesn't exactly answer my question.

Comment: `some odd reason allows me to log in with my old credentials` is because you added a second `root` user with a password. Your other user still exists. It would be more useful to know when/why the login failed before the re-install. It likely is the same issue. I'm not clear what you mean by `pre-existing database in phpmyadmin`. Seeing the PHP script you are having issues with would be useful. Likely you're using the DB in the connection string and it is unquoted.

Comment: Okay, I added the PHP in the post. When I say "pre-existing" I just mean I made the database before I re-installed and it's in the old user. I re-installed in the first place because the PHP was causing me an error with connecting to the database so I decided to change the authentication method which should fix it, that's why I didn't post the code. I figured it was already out of the way.